# Inserting image in a MAC Word Userform

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, userform

I am not a programmer so not sure what to do here. I would like an option of adding an image file in a Microsoft Word document userform for MAC. I had used a code earlier which works perfectly in Windows but it doesn't work for MAC and gives a 5948 error. I had added a field for the image in the userform with a button to add the image and the final submit button. The add button should allow the user to insert any size image from the local folder.

The code I was using is given below:

```
Dim ImagePath As String

Private Sub CMDAddImage_Click()

Dim objFileDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Set objFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With objFileDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "File Picker"
        .Title = "File Picker"
        If (.Show > 0) Then
        End If
        If (.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
            Call MsgBox(.SelectedItems(1))
            ImagePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ImagePath)

End Sub
```

And the code in submit button was:

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objShapes
Dim objSelection

'Set objSelection = ActiveDocument.Sections
'objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf & "One Picture will be inserted here....")

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Field04").Select
   Set objShapes = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

 objShapes.AddPicture (ImagePath)

End
End Sub
```

How can I edit the code for Mac? In Mac it does not allow to add the file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code for Windows, and what line errors.

Comment: Word 2011 or 2016/365/2019?

Comment: If the target users are on 2016 or 2019, you can use VBA to add a Picture Content Control. Then your document doesn't need to use a macro for adding a picture, the Content Control does it for you. Here's how: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.